# Component based angular 1.5.x

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading the [component page](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/guide/component) of angular docs, and there is a note:

> **An application is a tree of components**: Ideally, the whole application should be a tree of components that implement clearly defined inputs and outputs, and minimize two-way data binding. That way, it's easier to predict when data changes and what the state of a component is.

My question is:

In an application that have the architecture `Component > Controller > Model > Service`, should the `Controller` be a `Component` or just be a `Controller`?

Comment: why is this matter ?

Answer (score 0):

in angular 1.x a component is a combination of a directive+controller+template, if you are using a router, like ng-route or ui-router, you cant avoid using a controller. angular 2 is difffernet in this case but thats a whole other story.